# Java read/write: what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java

This is my code snippet:

```
byte value = (byte) rand.nextInt();
TX.write(value);                    
int read = RX.read() & 0xFF;
```

The hardware I am connected gives me back on RX what I write on TX.
That works OK as long as I am writing positive numbers,
BUT if I write a negative number what i get back does not match with what I wrote....

Please what am I missing?

---

EDIT: example output

```
Write: 66
Read: 66
OK AS EXPECTED

Write: -44
Read: 212
???

Write: -121
Read: 135

Write: -51
Read: 205
???

Write: -4
Read: 252
???
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write a negative byte and then you read it and assign it into an int using `RX.read() & 0xFF`, you will get a positive number, since the sign bit of the int will be 0.

Try

```
int read = RX.read();
```

Comment: doesn't work... :-((( what I read is different to what I write :-(((

Comment: @LisaAnne Can you give sample inputs and outputs that don't work? i.e. the values of `rand.nextInt()`, `value`, `RX.read()` and `read`.

Comment: @LisaAnne Eran is correct. Try `byte read = (byte) RX.read();`. And if you need it as an int, simply do `int readAsInt = read;` in the next line after that. If you want, you can instead "fix" your numbers by subtracting 256 from them if they are bigger than 127 (212 - 256 = -44, 135 - 256 = -121, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The BYTE is of 8bit out of which 1 is reserved for sign so max its range is from -128 to 127 so when you to the & 0xFF with the negative sign you will get the unsigned value of the range. hence when u r doing -4 it is giving 252 if u do the -1 then it will give 255 and so on.

Also in your code you can simple use int casting as it works at my end..
example:-

```
   byte b = -14;
    int i = (int)b;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that casting `int` to `byte` will represent the `int` as a `signed int` using two's complement (for one byte the range would be [`10000000`] -128 to 127 [`01111111`]; note that `-1` is `11111111` and `0` is `00000000`). However `RX.read()` treats the `byte` as an `unsigned int` (range from 0 [`00000000`] to 255 [`11111111`]).

If you only use one byte you can use:

```
int r = RX.read() & 0xFF
int read = -(255 - r) if r > 128 else r
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `0xFF` is by default an int which is 32 bits. Take -51 for example. In binary it is represented using 2's complement:

You are doing this:

```
                             11001101
& 00000000 00000000 00000000 FFFFFFFF
```

which gives

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11001101

= 205
```

What you want is

```
  11001101
& FFFFFFFF
```

so you should do

```
((byte) RX.read()) & ((byte) 0xFF)
```

See example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int negative = -51;
    System.out.println((int) (negative & (byte) 0xFF)); // = -51
    System.out.println((int) (negative & 0xFF)); // = 205
}
```